# Convert a String to customised version of Snake case and capitalise first character before every underscore in Java

Tags: java, string, snakecase

Suppose I have string like `FOO_BAR` or `foo_bar` or `Foo_Bar`,  I want to convert it to customised snake case like below

```
 FOO_BAR ->   Foo Bar
`foo_bar` -> `Foo Bar`
`Foo_Bar` -> `Foo Bar`
```

As you can notice all three inputs provide the same output, capitalise the first character before every underscore and first one, and remove the `_` (underscore).

Looked into various libraries like guava and apache but as this is **customized version** couldn't find any Out of the box solution.

Tried below code but and make it work but its looking bit complex

```
str.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").replaceAll("_", " ")
```

**Output of above code is like `FOO BAR` basically all characters in uppercase, that i can fix in another iteration but looking for something more efficient and simple.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for a bit of fun, here is a stream-based answer:

```
var answer = Arrays.stream(s.split("_"))
             .map(i -> i.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + i.substring(1).toLowerCase())
             .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: do you try that? \`foo_bar\` -> \`Foo Bar\`? or \`foo_bar\` -> Foo Bar?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast If we are talking about efficiency, the [answer by tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73646630/17795888) should be the best, single iteration, no intermediate strings, etc. About readability and simplicity though, stream beats the rest, true.

Comment: @Chaosfire agree, upvoting his answer as well but I need both hence selected the stream answer and upvoting others

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple implementation. I would add a few more test cases before I trusted it.
It does not handle Unicode characters of more than two bytes.

```java
public class Snakify {
    public static String toSnake(String in) {
        boolean first = true;
        boolean afterUnderscore = false;
        char[] chars = in.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if ((first || afterUnderscore) && Character.isAlphabetic(chars[i])) {
                chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
                first = false;
                afterUnderscore = false;
            } else if (chars[i] == '_') {
                chars[i] = ' ';
                afterUnderscore = true;
            } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(chars[i])) {
                chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]);
            }
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toSnake("FOO_BAR").equals("Foo Bar"));
        System.out.println(toSnake("foo_bar").equals("Foo Bar"));
        System.out.println(toSnake("Foo_Bar").equals("Foo Bar"));
        System.out.println(toSnake("àèì_òù_ÀÈÌ").equals("Àèì Òù Àèì"));
    }
}
```